# Rails for Zombies - Labs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html, canvas

I'm curious to know how the tutorial site "Rails for Zombies" did their labs. A user is required to answer a series of lab questions by typing ruby code into (what appears to be) a command line prompt to complete each lab. Upon submitting determines if they can proceed to the next lab question.

Peeking at the DOM through Firebug, it appears they're using the canvas tag- I'm assuming this is the command line, right? Also, on the Ruby side, how do they ensure that the code entered is what was required to answer the question? Or do they just have a test setup using RSpec/Cucumber?

Any help is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the in browser code editor we're using Mozilla Bespin, now known as [Skywriter](http://mozillalabs.com/skywriter/).  For the evaluation on the server side we are using a sandbox to run the Ruby code, as Andy Lindeman stated.  In most cases as you assumed, we're using tests to ensure the code does what you're supposed to do.

It's definitely not a simple piece of code.  If you're interested in using our engine to create a tutorial of sorts, please do get in touch. Gregg at EnvyLabs.

Comment: Hi Greg! Thanks for the response, it was very insightful. I need to pause and let you know that I can't believe you took time to post on MY question- you're like a celebrity! :)

Anyways, I was curious because I am an instructor at a community college and would like to leverage doing something similar to the labs for my students; this is a fantastic way to learn by entertainment. I would love to follow up with you and take you up on the offer to leverage the engine, or at-least have a chance to get familiar with the approach.

Again, a job well done! :)

Answer (score 6):

I do not work for Envy Labs, but I'd think that the Ruby code is simply sent as-is to the server, where it's run in some sort of sandbox.

It likely works similarly to [tryruby.org](http://tryruby.org/), whose source is [freely available for your reading pleasure](http://github.com/Sophrinix/TryRuby) :)